# Issue loading in variable length integer into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to MySQL and am attempting to load Fangrpahs standard team batting data (in CSV format) into a MySQL database/table. The issue lies in my last column (playerid). My data looks as such

```
"Name","G","AB","PA","H","1B","2B","3B","HR","R","RBI","BB","IBB","SO","HBP","SF","SH","GDP","SB","CS","AVG","playerid"
"Nomar Garciaparra","38","156","169","50","35","7","3","5","24","21","8","2","16","4","1","0","4","2","0",".321","190"
"Trot Nixon","48","149","167","47","31","9","1","6","24","23","15","1","24","1","2","0","3","0","0",".315","204"
"Manny Ramirez","152","568","663","175","88","44","0","43","108","130","82","15","124","6","7","0","17","2","4",".308","210"
"Johnny Damon","150","621","702","189","128","35","6","20","123","94","76","1","71","2","3","0","8","19","8",".304","185"
```

Note that player ID is either a 3 or 4 digit integer depending on the player

I have been encountering multiple errors regarding the input of the 'playerid' data type. First I created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE redsoxbatting2004 (
-> Name Varchar(20),
-> G int,
-> AB int,
-> PA int,
-> H int,
-> 1B int,
-> 2B int,
-> 3B int,
-> HR int,
-> R int,
-> RBI int,
-> BB int,
-> IBB int,
-> SO int,
-> HBP int,
-> SF int,
-> SH int,
-> GDP int,
-> SB int,
-> CS int,
-> AVG DECIMAL(3,3),
-> playerid int);
```

Next I attempted to load in my data to redsoxbatting2004 but received Error 1265

```
load data infile 'Redsoxbatting2004.csv' into table redsoxbatting2004
-> fields terminated by ','
-> enclosed by '"'
-> lines terminated by '\n'
-> ignore 1 rows;
```

`ERROR 1262 (01000): Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns`

I tried changing the deleting the data table redsoxbatting2004 and recreating with different data types for playerid to Varchar(50) and Varchar(4) only to receive the two following errors respectively.

```
ERROR 1262 (01000): Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'playerid' at row 1
```

I am not sure if this is a problem with my table generation, data input method or something else.

Thank you very much!

P.S This is my first question posed on Stack. If I have any formatting errors or if anything else can be done to make it proper please let me know

Comment: you should check the lines terminated of your file, and see if it is not  "\r\n"

Comment: I tested the file you gave above. It imported successfully, with no error. Then I edited the file to add `\r\n` as the line terminator (Windows-style text file) and then importing it caused the error you saw. So you should either fix the text file to have normal `\n` line terminators, or else tell LOAD DATA INFILE to use `lines terminated by '\r\n'`

Comment: I used ```lines terminated by '\r\n'``` and it worked properly thank you. Why would my file not have normal ```\n``` line terminators?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error there are more columns that you want to insert, than there are available in the table.

If a table has 2 columns for example, you can not insert 3 into it.

I would do a simple insert from the first record of the ckv file into the table, that way you can spot the extra column more easily.